# why gapi.hangout members are unavailable

Tags: google-hangouts, hangouts-api

i have been using `hangout api` but when i want to use `gapi.hangout` members such as events ,functions etc,they are unavailable just go and render are available i have referenced [platform.js](https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js) to my codes but i can't figure out 
what is my problem.

```html
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      
        gapi.hangout.onApiReady //is undefined
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found out i should have referenced [hangout.js](https://hangoutsapi.talkgadget.google.com/hangouts/api/hangout.js?v=1.0).

and now all members are available...